# Linq and ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, linq, observablecollection, entityset

I have a problem with Linq and ObservableCollections in my WPF application.

Context of the problem:

I've created a very simple SQL database with two tables: User and BankAccounts.
The User Table has an one-to-many relationship with the BankAccounts Table. Next I've created Linq-to-SQL dataclasses, which worked fine ==> the assosiation between the two tables was detected as well.

Next I've created a function to retreive all Users which works fine:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext

var query = from u in dc.Users
            select u;
```

Now suppose I want to add a new BankAccount to each user (not very likely but still).
I could add the following code

```
for each(User u in query)
{
   u.BankAccounts.Add(New BankAccount());
}
```

The above works all fine. The BankAccounts property is automaticly part of the User class, due to the assosiation in the database and Linq DataClasses.

However, in my application I first add the query results to an ObservableCollection. Hereby I could use all sorts off databinding and changenotification. This is accomplished by the following code;

```
ObservableCollection<User> oUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>(query);
```

**Problem:** Within the ObservableCollection I can't do anyting with the users BankAccounts property because it is now of type EntitySet<>. So I can't do the following statement anymore.

```
for each(User u in oUsers)
{
   u.BankAccounts.Add(New BankAccount());
}
```

Somehow, when queryresults are added to an observablecollection It is not possible to acces the user.BankAccounts properties anymore. However, it is possible to bind the BankAccounts Property to any control, like a listbox, and it contains the correct data.

Does someone now how I can create an observableCollction (or similar collection) from wich I can access these "assosiated" properties? I'm realy looking forward for to a solution.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,

Bas Zweeris
E: Bas.Zweeris@Capgemini.com

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the original `query` which will implement IQueryable, you can run any further queries you need against that.

The ObservableCollection should just be for WPF to have something to bind to - its very useful if you want to add a new collection item but not have it pushed to the database before the user has had chance to edit it.

eg.

```
// Create a new blank client type
var ct = new ClientType()
{
    IsArchived = false,
    Description = "<new client type>",
    Code = "CT000",
    CanLoginOnline = true
};

// Tell the data source to keep track of this object
db.ClientTypes.InsertOnSubmit(ct);

// Also add the object to the observable collection so that it can immediately be shown in the UI and editted without hitting the db
clienttypes.Add(ct);
```